# Trace Tomcat's web application

Tags: java, tomcat, trace

I meet a problem, it deploys a web application **TestWeb** in my tomcat7, I want to trace this running web application dynamically. Now I have attached an agent jar to tomcat successfully, but in fact I only trace the whole tomcat application not the **TestWeb**, I can't access any classes in **TestWeb**, I think it is ClassLoader's problem, I also think if I can get the WebAppClassLoader loading the **TestWeb**, Maybe it works, But I don't have a way to do, can you give me a suggestion?

Thanks & Regards.

Comment: What kind of information do you want to trace ?

Comment: I'm guessing you've deployed an app named TestWeb which doesn't respond when you go to localhost:8080/TestWeb? Check the logs in TOMCAT_HOME/logs to determine why.

Comment: no, the TestWeb is working well.

Comment: What about integrating a logger, which acts manually on called functions/services?

Comment: What software specifically are you using to try to trace it?